# how to refresh listview using arrayadapter

Tags: android, listview, search

I am working on getting the song played from the sdcard and when the particular song is being searched then on its OnItemClickListener() the particular song should be played. But the listview does not refresh by using adapter.setNotifydatasetChanged() method. 
Here's my code:

```
      mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
  android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, songs);
  mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

on search:

```
     inputsearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
            // When user changed the Text

            mAdapter.getFilter().filter(cs);
            updatelist();
            //mListView.invalidateViews();
            //mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
            //updatelist();



        }
    });
```

the playlist is generated using the cursor originally:

```
    private void generate_Playlist() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    uri = android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    String projection[] = { android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA,
            android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE,
            android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST,
            android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM,
            android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION };
    mCursor=this.managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
    songs=new ArrayList<String>();
    while(mCursor.moveToNext())
    {
        songs.add(mCursor.getString(1));
    }
}
```

And the updatelist():

```
    private void updatelist()
{
     mCursor=this.managedQuery(uri, new String[] {
              MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST,
              MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM,
              MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE,
              MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID,
              MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID}, null, null, null);

     //mAdapter.clear();
    mListView.invalidateViews();
    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

}
```

EDIT:
the updatelist method:

```
    private void updatelist()
{ 
     mCursor=this.managedQuery(uri, new String[] {
              MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST,
              MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM,
              MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE,
              MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID,
              MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID}, null, null, null);
     while(mCursor.moveToNext())
        {
            songs.add(mCursor.getString(1));
        }
     //mAdapter.clear();
    mListView.invalidateViews();

    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In `updatelist()` you're updating your `cursor`, but you're never updating your `songs` array. The `songs` array is not aware of the new `cursor`. So when you call `notifyDataSetChanged()` nothing changes.

So just repopulate your songs array after updating the cursor.

EDIT: copy paste the code you already have:

```
while(mCursor.moveToNext())
{
    songs.add(mCursor.getString(1));
}
```

Comment: and how do i do that?

Comment: that still does not work.i have given the edited code. that change still plays the song from old playlist.

Comment: Can you edit the question with updated code, to see how it looks now?

Comment: **First**: did you notice that the query in `updatelist()` is different than the original query? **Second**: You probably want to consider clearing your `songs` array before recreating it (`songs=new ArrayList<String>();`)

Comment: i tried that also songs= new arraylist<String>() after posting the code. but that also did nt work.

Comment: could you just tell me where do i use my mAdapter.clear() method?

Comment: yes the songs array is to be cleared so that it is recreated. but it doe not

Comment: Actually, I'm realizing that you should NOT create a new array (songs=new ArrayLizt) because the adapter still uses it. Instead, clear the array (don't remember the method... something like songs.removeAll() ???)

Comment: adding the songs.clear() method removes all songs from the list when the search func is being used. and then the new list is not created again. and the whole view is blank.

Comment: even if the songs.clear method is used alone without recreating it, the song that is played is from the old list only,,.. the list doesn get modified..

Answer (score 0):

The list you have passed to your adapter is songs. Hence every time you make a call to setNotifyDataChange() it will read the value from songs and update itself accordingly.

You have done this correctly in the generate_Playlist() methods as the list songs gets updated there. However in the updatelist() method, you do not make any changes to your list songs and hence calling setNotifyDataChange() has no effect.

I guess you would want to add the below (the way you have done in the generate_Playlist()),

```
 while(mCursor.moveToNext())
{
    songs.add(mCursor.getString(1));
}
```

or any other the way by which you want to update your songs.